# Consequence of Lebesgue Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, lebesgue-integral

If $a_{ij}\geq0$ if $i,j\in \mathbb{N}$, show using LMCT that,

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij}.$$

**Attempt:** Simply I can't realize how to use LMCT to prove it. I think that I'm missing an obvious fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n(i) := \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}$ and let $\mu$ be the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$. $f_n$ monotonically increases to $f(i) := \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}$. Then by LMCT
$$
  \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{N}} f_n(i) d\mu(i) 
= \int_{\mathbb{N}} \lim_{n \to \infty} f_i(n) d\mu(i)
$$
and this is equivalent to the equation you want to prove.

Comment: Thanks, I noted that this answer was incredibly clever. I would probably never have solved this problem by myself.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help